# Putting Webkit onto the Nautilus desktop (on Ubuntu Maverick) with PyGTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, desktop, nautilus

I can get what I think is the Nautilus desktop window by using this code:

```
screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()
for window in screen.get_windows():
    if window.get_name() == 'x-nautilus-desktop':
        xid = window.get_xid()
        wrapped_window = gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new(xid)
```

but when I try to do wrapped_window.add() I get the error that the Window Object does not have the add method.

I know this can be done since someone already has a youtube video demoing the effect at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOlIfhXQX9g but I can't figure out how to get the background window and put a widget on it.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up `gtk.Window` and `gtk.gdk.Window`. They are not the same. The former is a toplevel desktop window and functions as a container for GTK widgets; the latter is an abstraction of an area of the screen which can be drawn on top of, and is not a container.

You can't get an application's GTK widgets using libwnck. How to achieve the effect you want I don't know, but I think you need to look more into extending the window manager, since that is what manages the desktop.